# Best way to catch up local branch with remote origin when local is VERY behind

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch "branch" and a remote of that branch that others have pushed to and added content to. I know I can just checkout the local version of branch and `git pull`. The problem is my local version of "branch" is about 230 commits behind the remote. I know I know, I suck. There are a ton of merge conflict ad I was wondering if there was a better way to catch my local version up with the remote considering there are MANY merge conflicts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many commits has the local branch the remote branch does not have? You may want to use `git pull --rebase` if you want to prevent the (foxtrott) merge commit but you will need to resolve the conflicts anyways. Another way would be to make a copy of the remote branch and cherry-pick your local commits.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there was a better way to catch my local version up with the remote considering there are MANY merge conflicts

No, there is not. But that's not a bad thing. It just means you need to take a little time and do a little thinking.

**People tend to feel that a merge conflict is bad. I mean, it's written right there in the name: "conflict". Sounds kind of warlike, doesn't it? But really, that's a misconception. All Git really means here is: "I'm stuck, I need your help."**

When git merges, it is merely trying to enact two diffs simultaneously. (You can see what they are, before the merge, by saying `git diff ...otherBranch` and `git diff otherBranch...`.) The vast majority of the time, it can do that. But sometimes there are change hunks in those two sets that overlap or abut. One diff might change a word in a line; the other diff might change a different word in the same line. One diff might edit a file; the other diff might delete that same file. There is no automatic "right" answer in those situations; nobody has figured out a magic reliable rule for telling a computer how to proceed in those cases. We need some human judgement to help out.

I'm not saying, however, that you should just `git pull`. In my opinion, one should almost never `git pull`. Instead, `git fetch` to bring your remote-tracking branch up to date, and now *look* at what is going to happen and think about it. On one side, you have the local branch `branch`. On the other side, you have the remote-tracking branch `origin/branch`. Do a `git diff` and see what it would mean to merge them.

So now start the merge: be on `branch` and ask to merge `origin/branch` into it. A great deal of the merge will succeed, but some files will be left behind because they contain stuff that Git doesn't know how to handle. One at a time, deal with those files. Nothing horrible is going to happen. Take your time! Take the whole day. Take several days. It doesn't matter. Your files are not ruined. They are not sitting there in pain. On the contrary, each file is presenting you with a clear picture of what Git doesn't understand, and when you've got it worked out, you just tell Git that you've fixed that file, and you move on to the next file.

And if you totally regret the whole thing, you can always abort the whole merge and return to what things were like before you started it. But you won't have to. Resolving merge conflicts is *easy*. It involves elementary editing and thinking skills. So just go ahead and do it. Conquer your fear!

Comment: I was tempted to edit bold type in to the start of that second paragraph. And maybe edit out the "is a very complicated thing" sentence, it's really not, it's just that our usual tools for portraying the process don't really work well.  `git diff ...other` and `git diff other...` show the two sets of changes being merged, where they abut or overlap, Git generally needs help.

Comment: @jthill Well, feel free to edit! If I don't like something I can always undo just that part.

Comment: Okiay, sounds like a plan. I did a first cut, have at it,I'll be interested to hear what you think.

Comment: @jthill Good, I incorporated that into my own style.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assume your code is always correct in any conflict (or the remote is) with `-Xours` (or `-Xtheirs`).

```sh
git pull
git merge -Xtheirs origin/foo-branch
```

Whenever doing this, you are discarding some data (maybe a great deal), and so it will probably have **bad results**
To help with this, you should

- work in a *new branch*, comparing and merging this branch back into your original
- have good tests to catch errors or regressions
- thoroughly review the resulting code